# Having trouble at Veteran difficulty

Tags: mass-effect

I'm playin Infiltrator with Assault Rifle unlocked on Veteran difficulty. I'm currently 26 and having real trouble with pretty much any fight that contains more than three mobs. No matter what I do or what team I bring or what upgrades i have, we seem to be overwhelmed in seconds. I try to be tactical and move Ashley to the front and let Liara or Wrex use biotics but that takes down perhaps one or two mobs and then the rest simply swarm us. I don't even have time to use my sniper rifle. I actually timed one fight with geth from encounter to death and it was over in four seconds. Ashley got two-shotted and then I was swamped.

When reloading the outcome of the same battle is completely random. I had trouble with Benezia but at the fifth or sixth reload, I breezed through the battle and ended with near full health. Overall combat mechanics seem extremely arbitrary.

I'm thinking if lowering the difficulty because it's not really fun anymore. Especially when I don't even get a chance to be tactical. Not even Ashley or Wrex can survive that kind of onslaught, Liara even less. Is it supposed to be this way?

Comment: If you are that stuck in the game, I recommend a walkthrough like One-One mentioned. You can find tips to char. builds etc. to build the perfect squad.

Comment: its almost impossible to do well on higher difficulty without some serious crowd control ability, i.e. heavy biotics with lift/singularity

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**As with all difficult game settings: take cover, use stand-off tactics, use strategy and use squad powers to debuff any enemies in close range.** In short, Just don't charge into packed groups. And you going to still need cover almost right after you charge and fire off a shot or two.

**Remember to choose your squad wisely.** Strategy guides usually have tips on who to bring on a given mission. If you have trouble and you are using the same squad mates all the time, you should try to mix it up. Also remember to combine your squad members powers with each other and with your own for more devastating effects.

You're probably already doing it, but **using the correct weapon mods and ammunition also makes a world of difference**. Always be ready to switch out ammunition types if need be. In general you should be fine just using shredder rounds for organics and tungsten rounds for synthetics, but I find a few of the others can be useful in some situations.

In fights where you're quickly surrounded, **observe enemy behavior and take note of their weaknesses**. In these situations you need to find the fastest way to take the flanking enemies down, lingering around and trying to stay in cover will not do in these cases. Biotic abilities that temporarily disable the opponent are helpful here, as are a shotgun with heavy knockback that can knock down opponents. Also remember to use Damping against enemies with biotic or tech abilities to make their cooldown longer.

And yes Lady Benezia and the Krogan Battlemaster on Therum are some of the harder battles in ME1, so if you get through that you'll be in good shape! It doesn't get worse.

Answer (score 0):

Buy Colossus VIII - X armors.They come in medium and heavy. They are so ridiculously overpowered with Ablative/Medical Exoskeleton mods that you are virtually invulnerable even on insanity.

Damage protection should take priority over shields. Also keep in mind that Ablative mods stack on armor, so three Ablative X mods will give you 69% better damage protection, but poison damage seems to ignore dp making medical exoskeletons important.